# get_the_excerpt() not working in plugin loop

Tags: plugin-development, loop, excerpt

I am new in WordPress plugin development. I am developing a simple WordPress plugin in which `get_the_excerpt()` not working in the loop. Other tags such as `get_the_title()`, `get_the_permalink()` even `get_the_content()` working fine. Please somebody help me out on this. Here is the code

```
if($loop->have_posts()) : 
while($loop->have_posts()) : 
      $loop->the_post(); 
   $content .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br />'.get_the_excerpt().'</li>';
endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); endif;
```

Comment: Can you clarify "not working"? I assume you just get no output from `get_the_excerpt()`? Do you use [the more tag](http://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/more-tag/) in your posts?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic thanks again. Yes, you are right... when I add get_the_excerpt(), post pages stop loading. And yes I used more tag in my posts.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Unlike `the_excerpt()`, which auto-generates an excerpt from the content if one does not exist, `get_the_excerpt()` merely returns the contents of the `post_excerpt` field.</strike>

Instead, use `apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt() )`, which will trigger the same processing as `the_excerpt()`, but return the output rather than echo it.

Comment: Are you sure? According to the codex, both functions generated the same string but `the_excerpt()` directly display the string and adds opening and closing `<p>` tags around it.

Comment: Pretty sure. If you dive into `wp-includes/default-filters.php`, they're all attached to `the_excerpt` filter, but not `get_the_excerpt`.

Comment: This answer is correct.

Comment: I think you are both wrong. `get_the_excerpt()` returns the contents of the `post_excerpt` field and if is empty, then it auto-generates one by applying `wp_trim_excerpt` to the post content. `the_excerpt()` adds opening and closing `<p>` tags to the string generates by `get_the_excerpt()` and echoes it. See `wp-include/post-template.php`. So, both functions generates the same excerpt string (except for `<p>` tags). So, your answer doesn't respond to the Babu's question about why `get_the_excerpt()` is not working inside the loop.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I tried to use apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt() ) but it didn't work. thanks TheDeadMedic and cybnet for responding. Could you guys please tell me how I can fix it?

Comment: another thing I found post_excerpt is empty in the database.

Comment: @cybnet You're correct, `get_the_excerpt` does indeed apply `wp_trim_excerpt`. Answer amended.